# An identity involving the Weierstrass ℘-function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, special-functions

One of the most well-known identities involving $\wp$ is

[$$\wp'^2=4 \wp^3-g_2 \wp-g_3. $$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/23.3#E10)

However, when I run the command

```
WeierstrassPPrime[z, {g2, g3}]^2 - (4 WeierstrassP[z, {g2, g3}]^3 -
g2 WeierstrassP[z, {g2, g3}] - g3)
```

I get the same thing back, rather than $0$. I've also tried using `FullSimplify` as well as `FunctionExpand`, to no avail. Is there a way to make Mathematica see that this expression is zero, without manually removing it?

Thank you!

Comment: If you calculate the z derivative of the expression Mathematica simplifies it to zero. So the identity seems to be coded in somehow...

Comment: @ulvi  Only the second-order ODE satisfied by `WeierstrassP` is required to show that the derivative of the identity in the question vanishes.  The identity itself is not required.

Comment: Strangely, `FullSimplify[WeierstrassPPrime[z, {g2, g3}]^2 - (4 WeierstrassP[z, {g2, g3}]^3 -  g2 WeierstrassP[z, {g2, g3}] - g3), z == 2 && g2 == 1 && g3 == 2]` yields `0`, but `FullSimplify[(WeierstrassPPrime[z, {g2, g3}]^2 - (4 WeierstrassP[z, {g2, g3}]^3 - g2 WeierstrassP[z, {g2, g3}] - g3)) /. {z -> 2, g2 -> 1, 
   g3 -> 2}]` does not.

Comment: Checking numerically, 

`Table[
  WeierstrassPPrime[z, {g2, g3}]^2 -
     (4 WeierstrassP[z, {g2, g3}]^3 -
       g2 WeierstrassP[z, {g2, g3}] - g3) /. Thread[{z, g2, g3} ->
      RandomComplex[{-200 (1 + I), 200 (1 + I)},
       3, WorkingPrecision -> 50]] //
   Chop[#, 10^-20] &, 1000] // Union` evaluates to 

`{0}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is highly unsatisfying, but it works and may be of use in simplifying more complicated expressions involving `WeierstrassPPrime`. Define,

```
tf[e_] := e /. WeierstrassPPrime[z_, {g2_, g3_}]^2 -> 
    (4 WeierstrassP[z, {g2, g3}]^3 - g2 WeierstrassP[z, {g2, g3}] - g3)
```

Then, not surprisingly,

```
Simplify[(WeierstrassPPrime[z, {g2, g3}]^2 - (4 WeierstrassP[z, {g2, g3}]^3 - 
    g2 WeierstrassP[z, {g2, g3}] - g3)), TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf}]

(* 0 *)
```